# Finding the det:4x4 Matrix using inspection, not by direct evaluation?

Tags: matrices, determinant

I have the determinant of a 4x4 matrix I need to solve for uni. I understand that if a row (or column) is the same then  det of a matrix will equal zero, however the rows = the columns in this example. So this rule does not apply. I can not see a way to multiply a row or column to get zeros. And I'm not allowed to use gaussian elimination as that would be solving by evaluation.

I need to use properties of determinants, but I can not seem to figure it out. A hint I did get was C=the product of A and A transposed. The below matrix is C
 \begin{pmatrix}39&3&18&x\\ 3&86&-50&-6x\\ 18&-50&68&8x\\ x&-6x&8x&x^2\end{pmatrix}
I know the solution is 1764x^2, I am just unsure how to get there without solving on paper.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where did you get the problem?

Comment: @WillJagy It is on an assignment im currently doing

Comment: Are you sure Gaussian elimination isn't permitted and not, say, just computing the determinant itself?

Comment: @omer The question reads, "Find the determinant of the matrices below by inspection. That is by using the properties of determinants and not by direct evaluation (note: C=A*A(Transposed)). Give your reason(s) in each case."

Comment: Were you given matrix $A$, presumably with $\det(A)=42x$?  If so, note that $\det(C)=\det(A)\det(A')=(\det(A))^2$.

Comment: @RobPratt Wow, you are so right, i feel silly for not seeing that. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

To start,
$\begin{pmatrix}39&3&18&x\\ 3&86&-50&-6x\\ 18&-50&68&8x\\ x&-6x&8x&x^2\end{pmatrix}
=x\begin{pmatrix}39&3&18&1\\ 3&86&-50&-6\\ 18&-50&68&8\\ x&-6x&8x&x\end{pmatrix}
=x^2\begin{pmatrix}39&3&18&1\\ 3&86&-50&-6\\ 18&-50&68&8\\ 1&-6&8&1\end{pmatrix}
$.

Then you can start row and column operations.

I'll do a few.

$\begin{array}\\
\begin{pmatrix}39&3&18&1\\ 3&86&-50&-6\\ 18&-50&68&8\\ 1&-6&8&1\end{pmatrix}
&\to \begin{pmatrix}38&9&10&0\\ 3&86&-50&-6\\ 18&-50&68&8\\ 1&-6&8&1\end{pmatrix}
\quad \text{r1 - r4}\\
&\to \begin{pmatrix}38&9&10&0\\ 9&68&-26&0\\ 18&-50&68&8\\ 1&-6&8&1\end{pmatrix}
\quad \text{r2 + 3r4}\\
&\to \begin{pmatrix}38&9&10&0\\ 9&68&-26&0\\ 10&-2&2&0\\ 1&-6&8&1\end{pmatrix}
\quad \text{r3 - 8r4}\\
\end{array}
$

I'll leave the rest for you.

I know I'm not
taking advantage of the symmetry.

Comment: marty, I pasted in a congruence allowing rational numbers; just delete if you dislike, I was, well, taking a liberty. Sticking with integers, the calculation would be Smith normal form. My understanding is that Smith form may not be available as $P^T HP$ even though $H$ is symmetric. Maybe, maybe not

Comment: alright, Pari has Smith Normal form. Yay!

Comment: I was doing it by hand. You probably weren't.

Comment: I think I successfully edited out the computation I had put. Sorry for being pushy

Comment: That's fine. I have no problems with your additions.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.-Can you see why you do have

$$2^2x^2\det\begin{pmatrix}39&3&9&1\\ 3&86&-25&-6\\ 9&-25&17&4\\ 1&-6&4&1\end{pmatrix}?$$ There are several ways of reducing this numerical matrix. According with your post the determinant to be calculated must be equal to $(21)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

From the final comments below the answer, it would appear the OP was given the following information, where the first two matrices are transposes of each other. Perhaps just one of the (transposed) pair was displayed and given a name; probably the matrix on the left was shown and called $A.$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
3& 2&  5&  1 \\
0& 7&   -1& -6 \\
  0& 0&  2&  8  \\
0& 0&  0&  x \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
3& 0&  0&  0 \\
2& 7&   0& 0 \\
  5& -1&  2&  0  \\
1& -6&  8&  x \\
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
39& 3&  18&  x \\
3& 86&  -50& -6x \\
  18& -50&  68&  8x  \\
x& -6x&  8x&  x^2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$